# have problem with ceph fs mount

Tags: 14.04, mount, cluster, ceph

I want to mount CephFS with the kernel driver, but when I execute this command on my admin node

```
mount -t ceph 192.168.0.164:6789:/ /mnt/mycephfs
```

The admin node **hangs!** and I have to reset my machine.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) with kernel version is 3.16.0-60 and Ceph v9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It resolved itself when I [upgraded to Jewel](http://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-14-04-deploy-a-ceph-cluster-part-1/). The [release notes state](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/release-notes/#v10.2.0-jewel) that Jewel (the latest version) is the first release where Ceph FS is declared stable, but you can only have one metadata server.

> This is the first release in which CephFS is declared stable! Several features are disabled by default, including snapshots and multiple active MDS servers.